# Mass deleting magento products from csv

Tags: magento-1.7, magento-1.8, php-5.4, csv

I have this code that I have made. My aim is to delete products whose SKU is in csv

```
require_once '../app/Mage.php';
Mage :: app("default") -> setCurrentStore( Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID );
$skuAll =array();
$file_handle = fopen("skus.csv", "r");
while (!feof($file_handle) ) {
    $line_of_text = fgetcsv($file_handle, 1024);
    $allSku = $line_of_text[0];
}
$products = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection')
    ->addAttributeToSelect('*') 
    ->addAttributeToFilter('sku', array('in' => $allSku))
    ->load();
if(is_array($products))
{
    foreach ($products as $key => $pId)
    {
        try
        {
            $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($pId)->delete();
            echo "successfully deleted product with ID: ". $pId ."<br />";
        } 
        catch (Exception $e) 
        {
            echo "Could not delete product with ID: ". $pId ."<br />";
        }
    }
}
```

but its not working. Any help will be appreciated. I am using magento 1.7

Comment: what do you mean by "it's not working" ?

Comment: When I run the script it returns a blank screen. It does not delete the products

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you problem is this:

```
 if(is_array($products))
```

`$products` is not an array. It's an object. An instance of `Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product_Collection`.
Remove the `if` statement and see what happens.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it and its now working well. Thanks for the guidance

```
<?php
require_once 'app/Mage.php';
Mage::app("default")->setCurrentStore( Mage_Core_Model_App :: ADMIN_STORE_ID );
  $allSku =array();
  $file_handle = fopen("deletesku.csv", "r");
   while (!feof($file_handle) ) {
   $line_of_text = fgetcsv($file_handle, 1024);
$allSku[] = $line_of_text[0];

}
$products = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection')
->addAttributeToSelect('*') 
->addAttributeToFilter(
    'sku', array('in' => $allSku)
);


if($products && $products->getSize())
{
    foreach ($products as $product)
    {
        try
        {
            $product->delete();
            echo "successfully deleted product with ID: ". $product->getId() ."<br />";
        } 
        catch (Exception $e) 
        {
            echo "Could not delete product with ID: ".$product->getId()  ."<br />";
        }
    }
}else{
    echo 'Could not find any products';
}


 ?>
```